# Caching stored documents from MongoDB generically

Tags: java, mongodb, caching, guava, morphia

I am trying to optimize a game server for learning purposes. I am using MongoDB as a backend datastore with their Java driver. I am storing player data (level, name, current quest), quest data, and a range of other gameplay data in the database. Each document type has its own class type with the appropriate fields (e.g. `User.class` holds a document from the `users` collection, `Quest.class` holds a document from the `quests` collection, etc.

Right now, when a player performs an action, I am using the player's username to find a document from the `users` collection and update it accordingly. This is extremely costly as it means that every single time a user performs an action, a database query is needed to fetch the data for the current player.

Of course, my next thought was to load the player's user document when they connect to the server and store this separately, then remove it when they disconnect and save their updated data from memory to MongoDB.

The problem is that I would like to also do something similar for all the other collections and the only foreseeable way of doing this (as each cache has a different key to lookup data, usually Strings and UUIDs) is something like the following:

```
// Create a bunch of separate caches (faster than Guava Table, but ugly)
// For example, after finding a user: userCache.put("TheirUsername", user);
private HashMap<String, User> userCache = new HashMap<>();
private HashMap<UUID, Group> groupCache = new HashMap<>();
private HashMap<Integer, Quest> questCache = new HashMap<>();

// Or use a Guava Table to store all (this is slower than individual maps)
// For example, after finding a user: cache.put(User.class, "TheirUsername", user);
private Table<Class, Object, Object> cache = HashBasedTable.create();
```

**Are there any alternatives to having a large number of maps and storing the result of the find in these maps (one per cached collection)?**

I would love to somehow abstract this without causing a loss in performance. I have attempted to use Guava to implement a `Table<Class, Object, Object>` so that the cache is essentially dynamic and lets me cache any class. The problem is that Tables are a lot slower, especially if there are hundreds of lookups per second...

I am unsure as to how I can make this as optimal performance-wise as possible without compromising the clean nature of my code. A Table is essentially what I would love to do as it is very versatile, but it's just not fast enough.

Comment: Not your question, but you write about caching and a multi-user server: this feels like something with concurrent access, and none of your choices of data structures are thread-safe (`HashMap`, `HashBasedTable`). Use at least a `ConcurrentMap`, or look into Guava's `Cache` and `LoadingCache`.

Comment: @R.R. Thomas, Hi. Can you tell me how to implement caching DB for a single hashMap? Actually, I want to keep all the document of my single Collection in a HashMap for faster accessing. And then check the values in that HashMap instead of querying the collection every time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you could just use a single map from object to object. If your keys all have a correct equals()-method (all basic runtime classes have) you should not have any problems.

Thus, the basic answer to your question is:

```
HashMap<Object, Object> megaCache = new HashMap<>();
megaCache.put("someUser", someUserObject);
...
User cachedUser = (User) megaCache.get("someUser");
```

However, I strongly recommend *not* to do this!

You loose all the beauty and typesafety of generics and load up a single map with all kinds of stuff. (Usually, this is not a major problem concerning runtime, but the probability of having hash-collisions between unrelated key types raises.)

Rather go for single caches like in your original post and be typesafe and clear.

Comment: Moreover, there's the risk of conflicting keys between collections. There's no real way around having a cache per collection.

Comment: Interesting, didn't consider that option actually. Still probably not good to have a bunch of different objects. Fair enough, I guess I'll try and make do with the each individual ConcurrentHashMap or some sort of abstracted class containing a HashMap and "fetch" function. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @mtj. Can you tell me how to implement caching DB for a single collection? Actually, I want to keep all the document of my single Collection in a HashMap for faster accessing. And then check the values in that HashMap instead of querying the collection every time. Thanks

Comment: This totally depends on your actual requirements. Best, start of with searching for things like "java cache database" or sth, try coding a bit, then get eventual problems out of the way by asking the stackoverflow community and finally getting a review over on codereview.